# Bulk Insert Querying to import data from text file to a database table

Tags: c#, sql, bulkinsert

I have a text file with 25 fields, delimited with a pipe symbol.

Now, I have created a console application to import this text file data into the database table. In my database table, I have only 10 columns, and the user will choose the 10 columns from the 25 columns. So I have to import the specific 10 fields chosen by the user into the database. I am using the bulk insert query to import the text file into a temp table in my console application.

Now, how do I import only the user-chosen 10 columns from the text file to database table?
How do I modify the bulk insert query to achieve this?

Comment: Does the user get to map which source column goes to which destination column?  If so, do you need to worry about datatypes (ie - date/int)?  What happens if the user only selects 9 columns?  Why does the source data have 25 columns if you only need 10?  I'm assuming you're going to need some sort of dynamic SQL, but what exactly are you attempting to do here?

Comment: Thanks for replying me.
Yeah user will map which source column data is going to which destination column. u r right, i have problems with datatypes too.
I have an UI, where user have to map for all the database columns (all 10 columns). so there is no chance of mapping only 9 columns.
The Source Text file is from client, they will have n number of column datas in their file, but, i have choose the mapped columns alone.
wt i need is, how to pick the user mapped columns alone from the text file using the bulk insert or is there any other way to do so?

Thanks,
venkat

Comment: I'm assuming you have a predetermined set of fields in the file - why the heck are your users supplying a 25-field file?  Also, how 'smart' are your users going to be - and what's the potential for them to completely mess something in _your_ process up (ie, switching two like-typed columns).  Is there any way to pre-restrict certain columns - although this can be 'gotten around'.  Normally, you'd bulk-insert to a 25-field 'temp' table (all varchar columns), and then run a (dynamic, here) `SELECT` statement into your real (10 column) table.

Comment: Also, what about things like datatype conversions?  For example, a user may supply something that _to them_ looks like a valid date/time/timestamp value, but that your RDBMS can't (automatically) handle.  Actually, with dates, you may simply run into a problem where users could be giving you dates in *MDY format, but your server is expecting it to be in *DMY format.

Comment: hey, it seems, wt u have suggested is a good idea. can import all 25 columns in to a temp table with varchar data type for all columns except the 10 mapped columns. coz, for those 10 mapped columns, i can get the data type from the mapped table, so i can query that and construct a dynamic query like 10 mapped columns, i will put the exact data type in db and for 15 un mapped columns, i will put varchar(max). Now if i import this, i will get all 25 with 10 exact col's with its real data type. Frm temp table i will sel and move to my original table. i think it will work. will try this. thanks

Comment: Not to worry about the datetime columns, i am having those columns as varchar only.

Comment: Are you _storing_ them as `varchar`?  Bad idea - it means you lose the built-in methods for date math, the datatype protections for valid ranges (remember, 2/29 exists only _some_ of the time), and depending on format chosen, the ability to meaningfully sort your data.